# Can the debris found in seawater compromise the sealing of a subsea check valve?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, valves

In the event of a subsea check valve opening and debris lodging in the region where sealing takes place, could that make the valve not close when it should?

Would that happen to debris of any size? If not, how small would the debris have to be for that not to happen, i.e., should I add a filter to work around this issue, what filter accuracy should the filter have?

Could the filter accuracy be high enough to address this sealing issue and not limit the flow rate across the valve?

Comment: Yes, maybe, no - all depends on the debris...

Comment: @SolarMike I was thinking of any dissolved or suspended solids one may find in seawater. Even microorganisms if they were to be relevant in this context.

Comment: I guess the first question is the valve oriented to check outward flow or inward flow? Size matters too - 3 inch or 3 meters?

Comment: @PhilSweet the valve is oriented to check inward flow. I don't want seawater to flow inwards. The valve would have something like 3-5 inches.